# Break an comma separated address into multiple lines in the same column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that pulls details of clients including addresses. The addresses are in the form of 90 Howard Square,Old street, London, EC2 4RA, Uk. Now how can I display it as

90 Howard Square

Old street

London

EC2 4RA

Uk

on the aspx page gridview.

Comment: Can I have some code at where you are binding the address field?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to split these strings by comma and fill a `DataTable` which you can use as `DataSource` for the grid:

```
var tblAddresses = new DataTable();
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("Place");
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("Street");
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("City");
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("Post Code");
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("Country");

string[] input = new[]{"90 Howard Square,Old street, London, EC2 4RA, Uk"};
foreach(string address in input)
    tblAddresses.Rows.Add(address.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Now set it as datasource and databind it:

```
grdAddresses.DataSource = tblAddresses;
grdAddresses.DataBind();
```

Set the `GridView`s [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true` and you're finished.

**Edit** as @OGHaza has commented this gives you more than you actually want, here is a version that just inserts the tokens of the addresses:

```
tblAddresses.Columns.Add("Address-Part");
string[] input = new[]{"90 Howard Square,Old street, London, EC2 4RA, Uk"};
var allAddressParts = input
    .SelectMany(addr => addr.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
foreach (string part in allAddressParts)
    tblAddresses.Rows.Add(part);
```

Comment: @OGHaza: whoops, edited my answer.

Comment: Whoops, I deleted my comment assuming it didn't make sense now that you've changed your answer. Then I read your answer....

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Split to separate your address into a string[] of its parts. Then use String.Trim to remove the leading space on the parts. Then display the string[] using the gridview.